# how would Force.com Canvas SDK and canvas method "verifyAndDecodeAsJson" work with non-java platform? Is there any workaround?

Tags: authentication, canvas

I am using signed request as the method to POST the data to the canvas app. The canvas app is the SAP BSP page. I now seeing a big road block that I am not able to retrieve the values from the context that i have posted to it. Because there are some method which is dependent on Java but the canvas app platform does not support it. Now what should i do?

how would the canvas method verifyAndDecodeAsJson work with non-java platform?

Is there any workaround to make this work in javascript? Please suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the source code of the SignedRequest Java class is available e.g. in this [Verifying and Decoding a Signed Request](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connectpre/Content/canvas_app_unsigning_code_example.htm) which is a help. And there are JavaScript implementations of algorithms such HMACSHA256 in projects like [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

So a JavaScript implementation looks possible: perhaps there already is one somewhere? If there isn't someone with good JavaScript skills could probably write one in a few hours and if they were generously minded post it as open source.

**PS**

Found one via Google https://github.com/rajaraodv/salesforce-signed-request (that uses https://www.npmjs.org/package/crypto).

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. I would take a look immediately and get  back to you with queries if any. I thought canvas-all.js and json2.js is enough for writing publish and subscribe events on the canvas app side. But now i feel the lack of support from sfdc by not providing the work-around for other platforms which does not support. eg; SAP ABAP, SAP BSP, etc.

Comment: @BaskaranS Arguably its better to do what they have done: document the algorithm so it can be implemented fairly easily in any language: it uses pretty standard algorithms.